# Interpreting escaped chars in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

In JSON format, some escaped chars are interpreted as special chars (e.g. '\t', '\n'), but what about others - e.g. '\/'? Are they ignored and operated like non-escaped?

Comment: `/` is not a javascript text metacharacter. that's the rule for escaping, since json is basically "just javascript": if a character NOT being escaped could cause the string to be interepreted differently, e.g. the char is a metacharacter, then it has to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you escape a character that isn't part of a special escape sequence, it simply returns the character after the backslash.

This is explained in the syntax in section 7.8.4 of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> The CV of *CharacterEscapeSequence* :: *NonEscapeCharacter* is the CV of the *NonEscapeCharacter*.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the specs: http://json.org/

All valid escape sequences are explicitly listed under "string". I can't explain it any better than the graph there.

Answer (score 1):

Just try it.

```
> string = '"\\/"'
< ""\/""
> JSON.parse(string)
< "/"
```